# Изучение OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl, opengles

Подскажите пожалуйста, с каких материалов можно начать изучение OpenGL ES? Я для себя нашел Гинсбург Д. «OpenGL ES 3. 0. Руководство разработчика», на днях скорее всего куплю. Может быть есть еще какие-либо толковые книги?

Comment: OpenGL 4. Язык шейдеров. Книга рецептов. Хорошая книга можешь юзать

Comment: Посоветую от себя [Gameinstitute - OpenGL Graphics Programming](http://iv-torrents.ru/topic-game-institute-gameinstitute-opengl-graphics-programming-2016-eng-t=83890.html)  это курс видео 2016 года по OpenGL ~3.3 полному НО там вся геометрия с полными "выкладками" в виде картинок пояснений и качественных примеров. _Очень хорошо поясняет базис а примеры дают уснуть :3_ Если не поучиться  скачать то мне на почту на пиши я выложу в открытом доступе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в качестве дополнения, вполне полезным будет также ознакомится и с десктопным `OpenGL` например по [этим](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/) туториалам либо по [этим](https://learnopengl.com) - так как `E.S.` по сути это урезанная версия десктопного